# url not found for xml mapping in web.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jersey, mapping, web.xml

I have a basic question on how the xml mapping and the controller works. I have given different scenarios where it works and where I expect it to work and not working.

Jersey controller-

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
```

html Form - index.jsp

```
<form action="file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="input" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="input" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
    <br><br><br>
    <hr>
       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
       </p>
    <br>


       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>
```

URL Mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Application Name:RESTFileUpload

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTFileUpload - index.jsp page is returned.

http://localhost:8080/RESTFileUpload/file/upload - Page not found 404.
```

but when I changed "file/upload" to  "/rest/file/upload" the page is found

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTFileUpload/rest/file/upload
```

Question:-

Why the URL is not found when the form action is "file/upload" and url mapping is

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

http://localhost:8080/RESTFileUpload/file/upload - not found
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate..That ticket talks about the response object this thread talks about the URL mapping.

Comment: Basically, it's in conflict with the default servlet that serves the static content.

Comment: Thanks..Can you elaborate more on this or provide me a link that I can refer too?

Comment: There is a default servlet that serve up static content, like your html pages. That is mapped to `/*`. You have defined a Jersey servlet with the same mapping. The default servlet wins. It will not redirect to the Jersey Servlet. So if the default servlet can't find `file/upload` (which it won't as it's not designed to find Jersey resources), it will send you a Not Found